# Use regex to evalue string for repeated section

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, nsstring

I haven't used regular expressions yet in objective-c. What I'm trying to do right now is evaluate a string to see if it contains a 4 or 5 character repeating pattern - any pattern, it doesn't matter. For instance, a string like `@"testA54RqA54Rq"` would return a true value from the regex, while a string like `@"testA54Rq"` would not. Right now I'm just generating all possible 4 and 5 character substrings and matching them to each other, but obviously this is extremely inefficient. Where can I find some resources about how to start using regular expressions in objective C? If anyone's been in this situation before a small example would be nice.

**-EDIT-**

I would also like to have somthing like `@"testQWEr30BKRe40"` return true (pattern of 4 letters followed by 2 numbers). I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: They work the same as in other languagues. You use `NSPredicate` or (iOS >= 4.0, OS X >= 10.7) `NSRegularExpression`. See the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW9) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exact patterns you will be able to do such validation with regex `(.{4,5})\\1`

If you want to do category pattern, such as 4 letters followed by 2 numbers, then you have to:

1. replace all letters with one constant letter (for example replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `X`)
2. replace all numbers with one constant number (for example replace `\\d` with `0`)
3. validate such modified input with the same regex as shown above

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The actual regex I believe would just be: `(\\w{4,5})\\1`

---

```
NSString *regexStr = @"(\\w{4,5})\\1"; 
NSError *error = nil; 
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr options:0 error:&error]; 
if ((regex==nil) && (error!=nil)) {
  warn( @"Regex failed for: %@, error was: %@", string, error); 
} else {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. What method do I call in `NSRegularExpression` in order to evaluate a string and just get back a `bool` value?